# Android Bitmap animation along a parabolic path

Tags: android, animation, bitmap

[SurfaceView Animation of a ball from point A to point B and stop the ball at point B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaHYK.png)

Hello there guys, please help me with the problem as shown in the picture.

I am trying to come up with an animation of a bitmap (ball) moving from point A to point B along a parabolic path. Once the ball reaches point B it stops.The path of the ball is shown as a red line in the picture.

Comment: Is it for a game or just to show the user an animation?

Comment: it is for a simple game where the player will be clicking a ball that is at point a, when clicked it moves to point B and stops there until it is clicked and it moves forward to another point that is in front of point B.

Comment: use a `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Comment: @pskink I still fail to use ValueAnimator / ObjectAnimator, is there anywhere I can see it being put to practice like a working sample code of that. If there is an easier way of doing it, please advice me on how to do the animation. I hope you understand what am trying to do here looking at the picture.